# Data not being populated after altering the hive table

Tags: hive, hdfs, parquet

I have a hive table which is being populated by the underlying parquet file in HDFS location. Now, I have altered the table schema by changing the column name,but the column is now getting populated with NULL instead of original data in parquet.

Comment: The benefit of using Avro and/or Parquet is to be able to evolve the schema, which is what you are facing now.  Provide more info on exact changes or some sample of changes e.g datatype change, new additional columns, default values etc.

Comment: earlier table has column names like "sta_dte" of type "string" having default value as "9999-12-31" which were later transformed into "start_date" with same type and default value. But they are not being populated

Comment: try `aliases: ["old_column_name"]`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Open up the `.avsc` file.  For the column, you will find something like

```
{
    "name" : "start_date",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "start_date",
    "sqlType" : "12"
  }
```

Add an alias

```
{
    "name" : "start_date",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "start_date",
    "aliases" : [ "sta_dte" ],
    "sqlType" : "12"
  }
```